# How to compare to properties of an object from get-mailbox

Tags: powershell, variables, object, compare, sip

I am trying to confirm that the `userprincipalname` and sip address match for each user using `get-mailbox`. I know for a fact that some of the users do not match, yet my script is returning true for each mailbox. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited -OrganizationalUnit $_ | fl |
Select-Object DisplayName, 
    Samaccountname, 
    Userprincipalname, 
        @{n='EmailAddresses';e={$_.EmailAddresses | ?{$_ -match '^sip'}|%{$_ -replace 'sip:',''}}} | foreach{  If($_.emailaddresses -eq "$($_.Userprincipalname)"){'True'}else{'False'}}}
```

Comment: can you give me 1 example what you want to match, and another one which you dont want to match

Comment: I am not sure i understand. I am running get-mailbox against multiple OU's and getting the output displayname, samaccountname,userprincipalname and sip address for each user.For each user i am trying to verify that the userprincipalname and sip address are the same using an if statement that checks the $_.emailaddresses and $_.userprincipalname variables, but those variables do not appear to be the correct ones because im getting false for every person and 99% match so output should be true for almost all.

Comment: Have you checked `EmailAddresses` manually to confirm that they are correct?

Answer (score 0):

Never use a `Format-*` cmdlet in a pipeline unless it's the last step to show something to the user or you're going to save i using `Format-* | Out-String | Out-File`). The `| fl |` is breaking your pipeline because it ouputs special format-objects and not the original data. So start with:

```
$users = Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited -OrganizationalUnit $_ |
Select-Object DisplayName, 
    Samaccountname, 
    Userprincipalname, 
    @{n='EmailAddresses';e={$_.EmailAddresses | ?{$_ -match '^sip'}|%{$_ -replace 'sip:',''}}}

$users
```

Did it output anything? Are the values in the list correct? I don't have Exchange available for testing, but I thought `EmailAddresses` returned objects that you would use like this:

```
@{n='EmailAddresses';e={$_.EmailAddresses | ? {$_.PrefixString -eq 'sip' }| % { $_.AddressString }}}`
```

After you've verified that it looks okay, then you can add the automated test, like:

```
$Users | Foreach-Object {
    If($_.emailaddresses -eq "$($_.Userprincipalname)") {
        'True'
    } else {
        'False'
    }
}
```

or

```
$Users | Select Name, DisplayName, Samaccountname, Userprincipalname, EmailAddress, @{n="UPNandEmailMatch";e={$_.Userprincipalname -eq $_.EmailAddress }}
```